# Populating Variables Declared in Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm currently learning MVC 4 and Razor in Visual Basic.NET using this [Lynda.com tutorial](http://www.lynda.com/ASPNET-tutorials/ASPNET-MVC-4-Essential-Training/109762-2.html).

Right now, I have the main variables I want to be accessed throughout the website in a class called Auction.vb in the Model folder, the class having the following:

```
Namespace Models
    Public Class Auction

        Private Property x_ID As Long
        Private Property x_Title As String
        Private Property x_Description As String
        Private Property x_ImageURL As String
        Private Property x_StartTime As DateTime
        Private Property x_EndTime As DateTime
        Private Property x_StartPrice As Decimal
        Private Property x_CurrentPrice As Decimal

        Public Property ID() As Long
            Get
                Return x_ID
            End Get
            Set(x_ID As Long)

            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Title() As String
            Get
                Return x_Title
            End Get
            Set(value As String)

            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Description() As String
            Get
                Return x_Description
            End Get
            Set(x_Description As String)

            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property ImageURL() As String
            Get
                Return x_ImageURL
            End Get
            Set(x_ImageURL As String)

            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property StartTime() As DateTime
            Get
                Return x_StartTime
            End Get
            Set(x_StartTime As DateTime)

            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property EndTime() As DateTime
            Get
                Return x_EndTime
            End Get
            Set(x_EndTime As DateTime)

            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property StartPrice() As Decimal
            Get
                Return x_StartPrice
            End Get
            Set(x_StartPrice As Decimal)

            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property CurrentPrice() As Decimal
            Get
                Return x_CurrentPrice
            End Get
            Set(x_CurrentPrice As Decimal)

            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
End Namespace
```

This is being read by the new controller, AuctionsController.vb. This controller has the following:

```
Namespace Models
    Public Class AuctionsController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        '
        ' GET: /Auctions

        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Return View()
        End Function

        Public Function Auction() As ActionResult
            Dim test_auction = New MVCAuction.Models.Auction() With { _
                .Title = "Example Auction", _
                .Description = "This is an example Auction", _
                .StartTime = DateTime.Now, _
                .EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), _
                .StartPrice = 1D, _
                .CurrentPrice = Nothing _
            }

            Return View(test_auction)
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

The Auction() model is being read into the view of the same name, Auction.vbhtml. This view has the following:

```
@ModelType MVCAuction.Models.Auction

@Code
    Dim testauction = Model
End Code

<div class="auction">

    <h3>@testauction.Title</h3>

    <div class="details">
        <p>Start time: @testauction.StartTime.ToString()</p>
        <p>End time: @testauction.EndTime.ToString()</p>
        <p>Starting price: @testauction.StartPrice.ToString()</p>
        <p>Current price:
        @*
            Since CurrentPrice is nullable we have to check to see if it has a value before we call .ToString()!
        *@

        @If testauction.CurrentPrice = Nothing Then
            @: [No bids]
        Else
            @: <span>@testauction.CurrentPrice.ToString()</span>
        End If
        </p>
    </div>

    @If testauction.ImageURL IsNot String.Empty Then
        @: <img src="@testauction.ImageURL" title="@testauction.Title" />
    End If

    <div class="description">
        @testauction.Description
    </div>

</div>
```

Going into Visual Studio 2012, I put a breaking point within the AuctionsController.vb class at which the xauction variable is supposed to populate with the newly provided information. Instead, it shows that it's populating nothing, as seen below:
[image: properties within xauction isn't populating with new values for each property/variable]

As a result, now I get the following through my web browser:
[image: output on the browser]

I wanted to know:

1. Why even though I have the variables and everything declared are they not populating within the model; and
2. How do I have it so the newly populated information shows through the View without having to use ViewData or anything that passes the actual object?

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: do you mean to say test_auction is not populating?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `return View(test_auction);` line and inspect your `test_auction` variable.  Does it have the correct values?

Comment: @Guanxi I did mean to say test_auction I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, your `set` methods for all your properties aren't actually saving anything.

```
Public Property ID() As Long
  Get
    Return x_ID
  End Get
  Set(x_ID As Long)

  End Set
End Property
```

should be

```
Public Property ID() As Long
  Get
    Return x_ID
  End Get
  Set(value As Long)
    x_ID = value
  End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Thank you thank you @MattHouser! :) This did it. I can't believe it was something so simple.